# How to handle `OPTIONS` in Spock?

Tags: haskell, haskell-spock

I'm trying to init `ajax` request to backend which was built in `spock`

handling `post` and `get` request is quite easy, there are `post` and `get` from `spock` to handle these request.

- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-core-0.14.0.0/docs/Web-Spock-Core.html#v:get
- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-core-0.14.0.0/docs/Web-Spock-Core.html#v:post

when I'm trying to handle `prefight` request which inited by `ajax` library.
it requires `OPTIONS` verb, I failed to find one to handle that .

Pls kindly advise how to solve this issue ( handling `OPTIONS` verb in `spock`) ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of that module, `get` is defined as just `hookRoute GET`, and `post` is defined as just `hookRoute POST`, so just call `hookRoute OPTIONS` with the path and action you want to match.